# Count based on another column SQL

Tags: sql, analytics, zoho

I am trying to run an SQL query in Zoho Analytics to count the number of unique IDs (i.e. `Opportunities.Id`) for a given date range. But my `GROUP BY` query gives the error:

> Query Error: Improper usage of GROUP BY clause.
> Please ensure that all non-aggregate columns used in the SELECT clause are also used in GROUP BY clause.

The important part of the query is the line I'm using:

```
if(MONTH("Opportunities.Created Time")  = Month(Now() - 1), count(DISTINCT("Opportunities.Id")), '0' ),
```

Which is part of the full query here:

```
SELECT
         "Opportunities.Entity",
         count(DISTINCT ("Opportunities.Id")) AS 'Total Opportunities',
          **if(MONTH("Opportunities.Created Time")  = Month(Now() - 1), count(DISTINCT("Opportunities.Id")), '0' )**,
         count_if(("Opportunities.Stage"  = 'Deal Won')
         AND    ("Opportunities.Deal Type"  = 'New Deal')
         AND    (MONTH("Opportunities.Closing Date")  = Month(Now()) - 1)) As 'Deal Won Last Month',
         ((count_if(("Opportunities.Stage"  = 'Deal Won')
         AND    (MONTH("Opportunities.Closing Date")  = Month(Now()) - 1)
         AND    (("Opportunities.Deal Type"  = 'New Deal')))) / count_if((Month("Opportunities.Created Time")  = (Month(Now()) -1)))) * 100 AS "Conversion Ratio",
         sum_if(((MONTH("Opportunities.Closing Date"))  = ((month(now())) -1))
         AND    ("Opportunities.Deal Type"  = 'New Deal')
         AND    ("Opportunities.Stage"  = 'Deal Won'), "Opportunities.Actual Booking Amount") AS "Actual Booking Amount",
         avg_if(((MONTH("Opportunities.Closing Date"))  = ((month(now())) -1))
         AND    ("Opportunities.Deal Type"  = 'New Deal'), "Opportunities.Actual Booking Amount") AS "Average Booking Amount",
         sum_if(("Opportunities.Stage"  = 'Deal Won')
         AND    ("Opportunities.Deal Type"  = 'New Deal')
         AND    (Month("Payment Collection Info (Clubbed Duplicate OPP ID).Collection Date"))  = ((month(now())) -1), "Payment Collection Info (Clubbed Duplicate OPP ID).Collection Amount") AS 'Collection Amount',
         count_if(("Payment Collection Info (Clubbed Duplicate OPP ID).Collection Amount"  > 0)
         AND    (Month("Payment Collection Info (Clubbed Duplicate OPP ID).Collection Date"))  = ((month(now())) -1)
         AND    ("Opportunities.Stage"  = 'Deal Won')
         AND    ("Opportunities.Deal Type"  = 'New Deal')) AS "No of orders (collection)",
         sum_if((Month("Opportunities.Closing Date"))  = ((month(now())) -1)
         AND    ("Opportunities.Stage"  = 'Deal Won')
         AND    ("Opportunities.Deal Type"  = 'New Deal'), "Opportunities.Pending Collection") as 'Pending Collection'
FROM  "Opp+paymentinfo+users" 
GROUP BY  "Opportunities.Entity" /* This is a sample SQL SELECT Query */
/*Use "Control + Space Bar" to see other keywords*/
```

I tried using a *subquery* and *if* condition, however in both the cases the result is not coming. I need to able to count the id based on the month range.

Comment: Your posted SQL is invalid: e.g. your `**` chars. Please format it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this query , I think this can solve your issue.

```html
SELECT
    "Opportunities.Entity",
    COUNT(DISTINCT "Opportunities.Id") AS 'Total Opportunities',
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MONTH("Opportunities.Created Time") = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) THEN "Opportunities.Id" END) AS 'Previous Month Opportunities',
    COUNT(IF("Opportunities.Stage" = 'Deal Won'
        AND "Opportunities.Deal Type" = 'New Deal'
        AND MONTH("Opportunities.Closing Date") = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), 1, NULL)) AS 'Deal Won Last Month',
    (COUNT(IF("Opportunities.Stage" = 'Deal Won'
        AND MONTH("Opportunities.Closing Date") = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        AND "Opportunities.Deal Type" = 'New Deal', 1, NULL))
    / COUNT(IF(MONTH("Opportunities.Created Time") = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), 1, NULL))) * 100 AS "Conversion Ratio",
    SUM_IF(MONTH("Opportunities.Closing Date") = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        AND "Opportunities.Deal Type" = 'New Deal'
        AND "Opportunities.Stage" = 'Deal Won', "Opportunities.Actual Booking Amount") AS "Actual Booking Amount",
    AVG_IF(MONTH("Opportunities.Closing Date") = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        AND "Opportunities.Deal Type" = 'New Deal', "Opportunities.Actual Booking Amount") AS "Average Booking Amount",
    SUM_IF("Opportunities.Stage" = 'Deal Won'
        AND "Opportunities.Deal Type" = 'New Deal'
        AND MONTH("Payment Collection Info (Clubbed Duplicate OPP ID).Collection Date") = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH),
        "Payment Collection Info (Clubbed Duplicate OPP ID).Collection Amount") AS 'Collection Amount',
    COUNT_IF("Payment Collection Info (Clubbed Duplicate OPP ID).Collection Amount" > 0
        AND MONTH("Payment Collection Info (Clubbed Duplicate OPP ID).Collection Date") = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        AND "Opportunities.Stage" = 'Deal Won'
        AND "Opportunities.Deal Type" = 'New Deal') AS "No of orders (collection)",
    SUM_IF(MONTH("Opportunities.Closing Date") = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        AND "Opportunities.Stage" = 'Deal Won'
        AND "Opportunities.Deal Type" = 'New Deal', "Opportunities.Pending Collection") AS 'Pending Collection'
FROM "Opp+paymentinfo+users"
GROUP BY "Opportunities.Entity";
```

Comment: Thank you so much, my issue is resolved.

Comment: Hey I did it, I am new to platform it says I don't have permission.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).